# Insert QTreeWidget into QQuickWindow child element

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'd like to insert a QTreeWidget into my top level QQuickWindow.  Is it possible?  The code below is commented to show my general idea.

### IDEA.CPP

```
....
//in main somewhere
QTreeWidget *tree = new QTreeWidget();

//Magically insert tree into window
....
```

### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<Data>();


    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("classInstance", new polysync_api_wrapper);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("trace", new Trace);

    engine.load(QUrl("qml/main.qml"));
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);

    window->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

### main.qml

```
ApplicationWindow {

    ......
    Rectangle {
        id: treeWindowContainer
        ....

        --->**TREE WIDGET GOES HERE PLZ!?   SUCH AMAZE!!!**<---
        ....
    }

}
```

Thanks all!  All *somewhat decent* suggestions get upvotes !!!  It's Friday !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  an item that wraps a `QWidget`. There's no such item, but the closest you get is `QQuickPaintedItem`. You'd need to derive from it and write an item that can take an instance of `QWidget` and use its `render` method to paint the item. There's also work to be done on forwarding the events between the two.